# JavaScript compare two strings with the same value fails

Tags: javascript, php, string

I'm trying to compare two strings which seems containing the same value but it doesn't work.

here is my code:

```
ABC.prototype.is_in_DB = function () {
    var ans = "";
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            ans = (xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
        return ans;
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "ABC_DB.php", false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("id=" + this.get_id() + "&name=" + this.get_type() + "&description=" + this.get_description() + "&kind=" + this.get_kind());

    var check = "true";

    console.log("this is ans type    " + typeof (ans));
    console.log("this is ans length    " + ans.length);
    console.log("this is ans     " + ans);
    console.log("this is check type    " + typeof (check));
    console.log("this is check length    " + check.length);
    console.log("this is check     " + check);

    if (ans === check) {
        console.log("the if is true ");
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log("the if is false ");
        return false;
    }
}
```

the php file works and it's end looks like this (there are no more echo commands in the file)

```
 if ($row_cnt>0){
     echo('true');
 } else {
     echo('false');
 }
```

when I'm printing the values of the strings i receive the following

> this is ans type    string
>
> this is ans length    5
>
> this is ans     true
>
> this is check type    string
>
> this is check length    4
>
> this is check     true
>
> the if is false

Do you have any idea how I can compare it?

Comment: looks like ans contains some white space from response so use `ans.trim() == check`

Comment: Why are you doing synchronous ajax?  Eeeck.  Lock up the browser during the ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do ans.trim() and using == instead of ===
It seems that ans could also have a trailing character like a \n

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess here, but because the length of "ans" is 5, but the value is "true", I'm willing to bet there is a space in there. Try adding **trim(ans)** before your echo's, and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your responseText is coming with some white spaces.

Try to use: `if (ans.trim() == check)`

Answer (score 0):

try eliminate the possibility that `ans` and `check` are not the same object use `==` instead `===`

Answer (score 0):

thanks to everybody.
what i found that works for me was to add this two following line

```
x=(xmlhttp.responseText);
ans=x.replace(/^\s*/,'').replace(/\s*$/,'').toLowerCase();
```

the problem i faced was due to additional white spaces.
this line eliminate them.